# Problems with Microk8s registry

Tags: docker, containers, virtual-machine, registry, microk8s

I have two virtual machines: one with microk8s and another without microk8s. In order to build containers, I use the Microk8s registry to save my docker image. To ahieve this, I execute this commands:

> microk8s enable registry
> docker build . -t dirIPoftheVM:32000/vnf-image:registry

> echo '{"insecure-registries": ["dirIPoftheVM"]}' | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json

> sudo service docker restart

> docker push :32000/vnf-image:registry

In the other machine, I execute:

> docker run dirIPoftheMV:32000/vnf-image:registry

and it returns the following error:
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://dirIPoftheVM:32000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

How can I solve this?

Comment: In the 2nd-docker-run machine, you need to also allow the `insecure-registries`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with this but, with helm chart it doesn't work

Comment: You need to create another question for your `helm` issue

Comment: Okey, if you know, that question is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234164/imagepullbackoff-from-a-local-registry-microk8s-allocated-in-other-virtual-mac?noredirect=1#comment132761096_75234164