# ImagePullBackoff from a local registry (microk8s) allocated in other virtual machine

Tags: repository, virtual-machine, registry, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I follow all the instruction from the Microk8s registry page, but when I try to obtain the image from my Helm chart (allocated in other virtual machine), it returns an ImagePullBackOff.
I've inserted in my virtual machine the insecure-registries: 192.168.56.11:32000 and the command docker pull 192.168.56.11:32000/image:registry works fine.

My helm chart values.yaml file looks like this:

```
image:
    repository: 192.168.56.11:32000/image
    pullPolicy: Always
    tag: "registry"
```

Comment: This seems much more about your registry and cluster setup than anything in your Helm chart.  I'd expect you'd have the same trouble `kubectl apply` the same YAML content without Helm, and the thing you have to debug is why exactly the image pull is failing; not anything programming-related.

Comment: Did you updated the `hosts.toml` files?

Comment: I've done that but It still doesn't working

Comment: Debugging with the command kubectl describe I can see that it failed the request 192.168.56.11:32000/v2/vnf-image/manifests/registry because server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client. However, I've put the insecure-registries line in both machines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify Image

Taking the URL in error, e.g. http://192.168.56.11:32000/v2/vnf-image/manifests/registry, access via Web Browser to make sure the image is correct, e.g. no issue of "manifest unknown"

2. Configure microk8s properly

Following https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private?
can take **snap info microk8s** to check the version

Answer (score 0):

Well, my case was significantly different and special. I was using two VMs: one with OSM (Open Source Mano) and another with microk8s. Despite I configure my helm charts in the OSM machine, it is in the microk8s machine where it pull the image, so I had to put localhost:32000/image:registry in the helm chart.

This is an special issue due to the use of OSM and microk8s in different machines.

I hope this will be helpfull to someone.